# Insert customized dexterity content type to tinymce editor in plone 5

Tags: javascript, python, tinymce, plone, dexterity

Suppose I have a dexterity content type called 'Unit' in plone 5.
I am looking for solutions of these following questions :

1. How to create shortcut in tinymce to insert 'Unit' to tinymce editor (like the way we insert image)?
2. Suppose the 'Unit' object is stored in rich text field using
   html object tag. How can I modify [Products.TinyMCE](https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE) to be able to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Such object buttton already resolved in the [collective.embedly](https://github.com/collective/collective.embedly) product

You can duplicate a frame therefrom:

**registered toolbar:**

http://portal/@@tinymce-controlpanel

- Custom Toolbar Buttons

  ```
  embedlylink
  ```
- Custom Plugins

  ```
  embedly|/++resource++collective.embedly.plugin/editor_plugin.js
  ```

**plugin structure:**

JS: [browser\plugin\editor_plugin.js](https://github.com/collective/collective.embedly/blob/master/collective/embedly/browser/plugin/editor_plugin.js)

PT: [browser\plugin\embedly.htm](https://github.com/collective/collective.embedly/blob/master/collective/embedly/browser/plugin/embedly.pt)

[zcml resource](https://github.com/collective/collective.embedly/blob/master/collective/embedly/browser/configure.zcml#L31): browser:resourceDirectory name="collective.embedly.plugin" directory="plugin"

install: [setuphandlers.py](https://github.com/collective/collective.embedly/blob/master/collective/embedly/setuphandlers.py#L122) : add_tinymce_plugin()

**object**

Further object html tag is marked as nasty tag:

http://portal/@@filter-controlpanel

[remove it](https://plone.org/products/tinymce/documentation/how-to/how-to-use-rich-media-with-tinymce) from this list